# Migrating a date field date created to SharePoint's Created

Tags: list, migration, sharepoint-enterprise, lotus-notes

Can we migrate a date field called date created from lotus notes to SharePoint "Created" date field (which is a readonly field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Quest migration tool i created the share point column called Created and data type as Date, and the mapped the lotus notes column date created to it...and now it does get the migrated date field in the created date field share point

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to update/overwrite the Created field (and other fields shown below) after the item is created as shown below

```
objItem [SPBuiltInFieldId.Created] = new DateTime(2008, 5, 5);
objItem [SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = "{author}";
objItem [SPBuiltInFieldId.Editor] = "{editor}";
objItem [SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified] = new DateTime(2008, 5, 6);
objItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

Also take a look: http://blogs.edwardwilde.com/2010/04/21/how-do-you-update-the-author-or-created-by-and-editor-or-modified-by-last-modified-fields-of-a-list-item-splistitem/